# If you can say that something is pending, can you say that it pends or pended?

Tags: grammar, verbs, word-usage, tenses

> The debit card transaction is pending.

This is correct.

> Debit card transactions often pend for a day or two.

> The debit card transaction pended for two days.

Are these correct?

Comment: No, they’re not correct.

Comment: Have you tried looking up "pend" in a dictionary? What did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it if you want to. The verb "pend" in the sense of "delayed" is archaising. Other words such as "suspend", "pending" are more commonly used.[image]

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pend